# Android MVI how to handle event changes?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I watched some MVI courses, and I don't understand what is the purpose to handle events this way:

So the viewModel collects the events and does something base on that.

Anyway why should I save the actual event?

ViewModel:

```
  private val _event = MutableStateFlow<HomeEvent?>(null)
    
    init {
        listenEvent()
    }
    
    private fun listenEvent(){
        viewModelScope.launch { 
            _event.collectLatest { 
                //login to handle events
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun setNewEvent(e: HomeEvent){
        _event.value = e
    }
```

Instead of this, isn't easier to merge the setNewEvent and listenEvent functions, and the view can call it? So like this:

```
fun onNewEvent(e: HomeEvent){
        //login to handle events
    }
```

Comment: if you find one approach easier than another and it still gives you the desired result, then use that. if there was really only one correct way of doing something, it would have been enforced

Comment: usually viewModel event listener is for UI events. For example if user clicks update button then you just need to handle that event from viewModel by making request to update list or something else. By this way you get rid of directly calling viewModel methods, which means you delegate such calls with events. With events it will be easier to you in future to grab Logs, crashes or make Analytics since you have single source

Comment: @Jamshid: Thanks, it makes sense, in my examples, the Ui just calls a viewModel method to do somethin by event. The differences are the first implementation holds the actual event in the viewModel, and the viewModel also listens to its changes. So both implementations meet the single source I think.

Comment: @Andreas1234 think about adding logs/analytics on your every viewModel method call through UI. It will add extra codes/lines and you need to repeat such logic. And think about adding logs/anayltics only in event listener so in future if someone want to add new method to ViewModel it will guarantee that logs/analytics will be included. While adding it manually to method by someone who don't know about logs/analytics can miss them

Comment: @Jamshid I think you misanderstand me, or I you :D So in my implementation, rhe viewMoldel would have a a method called onNewEvent(). The ui can call only just this event, and it passes the type of event. So my implementation wouldn't store the actual event, it just handles it. So in your example, I could put the logs/analytics into this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I saw only one time somewhere the first implememtation from my examples, but usally the approach is more similar to my second example(which is my implementation)